# Fargate task AWSSecurityTokenService Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, prometheus, aws-fargate

I am trying to get Prometheus' CloudWatch Exporter running as a Fargate task. I am building a custom image with the config file baked in based on the `prom/cloudwatch-exporter` image.

When the container comes up I am seeing the following error in the logs:

> com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AWSSecurityTokenServiceException: Access denied (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: REQUEST-ID)

The call that produces that error appears to be this:

> at com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.AmazonCloudWatchClient.listMetrics(AmazonCloudWatchClient.java:684)

Both the Task Execution Role and the Task role have the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                "cloudwatch:ListMetrics"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the container definition:

```
{
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "LOG-GROUP",
          "awslogs-region": "REGION",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "LOG-PREFIX"
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": null,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 9106,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 9106
        }
      ],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 0,
      "environment": [],
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": null,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "image": "ACCOUNTID.dkr.ecr.REGION.amazonaws.com/mycustomimage:latest",
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "container-name"
    }
```

Why is the container not authenticating based on the IAM policies? Every other policy in the setup appears to be working as expected. The cluster can pull the custom image from the ECR repo, logs are being written, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. CloudWatch Exporter lets you pass the IAM role arn via the config attribute `role_arn`. If this value is set, then the app uses `STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider` to establish credentials. This is apparently not supported in Fargate (this method works in EC2-based ECS containers). If you leave off `role_arn` then the app creates a new client with default settings, which uses the `DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain` class and this works like a charm.

Comment: DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain works only if the resource is in same account. How to support cross-account access in Fargate using IAM roles?